# Отображение controls в bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, hover

Использую дефолтную [карусель bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel). Хочу что бы оба carousel-control появлялись при :hover на слайдер. Собственно для этого задаю:

```css
.carousel-control {
  display: none
}
.carousel-inner:hover + .carousel-control {
  display: inline-block
}
```

В итоге controls не отображаются, но при :hover на .carousel-inner появляется только левый. Достаточно странно потому что display: none сработало на оба .carousel-control. Других изменений касающихся отображения не вносил.
Подскажите, будьте добры в чем проблема, если кто сталкивался с чем-то подобным.

Comment: Попробуйте изменить на это `.carousel-inner:hover ~ .carousel-control`

Comment: Никогда не слышал о такой форме записи, но она работает. Благодарю Вас. Не могли бы Вы скинуть ссылочку на информацию/документацию по такой форме записи?

Comment: Вот информация: http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/sibling ; Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/ga2r1yoe/